# background-image won't show on site but will in Dreamweaver

Tags: css, background-image

I'm having a problem where I have a background image that will show up perfectly fine when I'm using it in dreamweaver, but once I upload my site and the CSS files and everything it won't show.

Here's my CSS code:

```css
.ELSsubbg {
    background-image: url('../images/NTG_images.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top left;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you view the image at `../images/NTG_images.jpg` in your browser?

Comment: Did you flush your browser catch with e.g. `ctrl+f5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a relative path in your CSS, where the stylesheet is looking for the image may be different than where you are seeing it when you go to it directly in the browser.

Try using an absolute path to your images directory instead of a relative one. Assuming you can see the image in your browser at `http://www.website-name.com/images/NTG_images.jpg` try removing the dots to make the path absolute from the root of your website.

```
background-image: url('/images/NTG_images.jpg');
```

Comment: Tried this for the second picture that wasn't working. Fixed it right away. Thanks

Comment: +1 for the right answer. This is basically what I was trying to hint at with my answer. I guess I was too subtle? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you uploaded the image? Have you uploaded it to the right place? Is the CSS looking for it where you think it should be?

The easiest way to answer these questions is to use the browser's developer tools (eg Firebug) to watch the network traffic your page generates. Look for the request where it tries to load the graphic. Is it giving a 404 error? Probably.

If you are getting a 404, look at the URL it's calling to find out why. The answer should become clear.

Comment: I checked again with firebug, and it said the image failed to load, so I tried the same style with a different picture and that worked. So now I just need to figure out why my picture wasn't loading, it has been uploaded but it won't load on the page for some reason.

Comment: So yeah. I tried just renaming that picture, and it worked. I guess it just didn't like the name. Sorry for the waste time.

Comment: no worries. might have been capitalisation? your windows system wouldn't care about filenames being upper or lower case, but the linux web server would care. it's a common enough problem.